# Is there a fast test that can definitively say if your macbook harddrive is physically broken?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, boot

My friend's MacBook Pro won't progress past the apple icon.  My feeling is that this means the hard drive will not boot.  **Are there definitive steps that can be taken to diagnose the boot process and is there a fast test that can definitively say if your macbook harddrive is physically broken?**

I have advised them to hold down the option key on boot to bring up the startup disk manager.  If they do not see their hard drive as an option this would imply a problem mounting the hard drive - either broken or the connection dislodged.  At this time they do not hear the hard drive "click of death".

They DO NOT have the question mark folder:
[image]

They DO have the frozen apple icon:

[image]

Are there more definitive steps that can be taken to diagnose the boot process?  **Is there a differential diagnosis that can account for the presence of the frozen apple screen and the absence of the "question mark folder" screen?**

Answer (score 3):

I would boot into the [Apple Hardware Test utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509), or, if the Mac is newer than June 2013, the [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781) tool.

Start the Mac and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> button right after booting.

This will run some checks on memory and hard drive, amongst others, and report you the results.

Answer (score 1):

Without opening the laptop probably not, if you open it you could grab the harddrive and perform a diskcheck on it

I've only seen that once and it was a harddrive issue, but I'm not confident enough to diagnose that for you :\

Comment: I also think it could be a hard drive issue, but I have seen the "?-folder" in the past when that was the case, but this time only see the frozen apple icon screen.  Will try the Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnistics tool.

Comment: Yeah definitely do that, I'm not sure how I forgot that existed...

Good luck!